# Cannot write required AWS Cognito attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I created a user pool in AWS's Cognito, specified `given_name` and `family_name` as required user attributes. I also added an app and checked the permissions :

[image: attribute permissions for app]

If - using the [Cognito Identidy SDK](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/main/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js) - I try to register a user and omit the attributes, I get: "Attributes did not conform to the schema: given_name: The attribute is required family_name: The attribute is required" which is expected.

If I include the attributes:

```
const firstNameAttribute = new CognitoUserAttribute({ Name: 'first_name', Value: firstName });
const lastNameAttribute = new CognitoUserAttribute({ Name: 'last_name', Value: lastName });
cognitoUserPool.signUp(username, password, [firstNameAttribute], [lastNameAttribute], callback);
```

The server returns

```
{
    "__type":"NotAuthorizedException",
    "message":"A client attempted to write unauthorized attribute"
}
```

How can I fix this and let users set their name during registration?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check Write permission is allowed in app client.

Location:

> Amazon Cognito > User Pools > {User Pool} > App Integration > App
> Client > Attribute read and write permissions > Edit

Answer (score 0):

The app in which the users would try register sent the wrong field names :(